# Solving the non-homogeneous two dimensional heat equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation, fluid-dynamics, greens-function, fundamental-solution

I am currently interested in solving the inhomogeneous heat equation for a two dimensional flow for a bounded domain. The PDE is given as:

$\frac{\partial u_1'}{\partial t}-\nu(\frac{\partial^2 u_1'}{\partial x_1^2}+\frac{\partial^2 u_1'}{\partial x_2^2})=f(x_1,x_2,t)$

with $f(x_1,x_2,t)=cos(\sqrt{a}x_1)cos(\sqrt{b}x_2)e^{-\nu(a+b)t}$.

I was thinking about solving this by using the Fundamental solution for two dimensions, given as:

$\Phi ={\frac {1}{\sqrt {(4\pi \nu t)^{n}}}}\exp \left(-{\frac {\mathbf {x} \cdot \mathbf {x} }{4 \nu t}}\right)$

The solution would then be given (atleast for the 1D case) as:

$u_1^{'p}=\int_0^t \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\Phi(\vec{x}-\vec{y},t-s)f(\vec{y},s)d\vec{y}ds$

However since the inhomogeneous function is given as a rather "complicated" structure in terms of integration, I struggle quiete a lot there.

Do you have any ideas or experience in how to solve suche an inhomogeneous heat equation?

I would also appreciate any guidance in how to solve the inhomogeneous heat equation in genereal for a two dimensional flow, because I am not quite sure if this approach is the correct one.

I am very thankful for any advice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The PDE is linear so the general solution is the sum of a homogeneous and particular solution, $u = u_h + u_p$.

The particular solution satisfies

$$ \frac{\partial u_p}{\partial t} - \nu \left(\frac{\partial^2 u_p}{\partial x_1^2}  + \frac{\partial^2 u_p}{\partial x_2^2}\right) = f $$

Making the ansatz $u_p(x_1,x_2,t) = T(t)\cos (\sqrt{a}x_1)\cos (\sqrt{b}x_2)$ and subsituting into the PDE, we get

$$T'(t)\cos (\sqrt{a}x_1)\cos (\sqrt{b}x_2) + \nu T(t)(a+b) \cos (\sqrt{a}x_1)\cos (\sqrt{b}x_2) = e^{-\nu(a+b) t}\cos (\sqrt{a}x_1)\cos (\sqrt{b}x_2), $$

and a solution is obtained when

$$T'(t) + \nu(a+b)T(t) = e^{-\nu(a+b) t}$$

Solving the ODE with an integrating factor we get  $T(t) = (C+t)e^{-\nu (a+b)t}$, and the particular solution is

$$u_p = (C+t)e^{-\nu (a+b)t}\cos (\sqrt{a}x_1)\cos (\sqrt{b}x_2)$$

As you have not specified an initial condition, nothing can be said yet about the constant $C$ appearing in the solution.

---

It remains to solve the homogeneous part,

$$ \frac{\partial u_h}{\partial t} - \nu \left(\frac{\partial^2 u_h}{\partial x_1^2}  + \frac{\partial^2 u_h}{\partial x_2^2}\right) = 0$$

As you want to solve on a "bounded domain", once you supply the initial and boundary conditions you can apply separation of variables seeking a solution of the form

$$u_h(x_1,x_2,t) = X_1(x_1)X_2(x_2)T(t)$$

Comment: Thank you sooo much @RRL you really helped me sooo much.

Comment: @JuliusAgnus: You’re welcome.

Comment: @RR Hi! I am working on a similar problem with a different inhomogeneous part, i.e.,  $f = \exp \Big[-6\Big((x + \frac{1}{2})^2 + y^2\Big) \Big] -  \exp \Big[-6\Big((x - \frac{1}{2})^2 + y^2\Big) \Big]$. 
Can you please explain how you came up with the ansatz for p.s.: $u_p$ or somewhere I can refer to understand it? Thank you so much.
Given that $u(t=0) = (1-y^2)x$.

Comment: @Grazel: In this case it was easy to guess because the spatially dependent factor in $f$ is $g(x_1,y_1) = \cos(\sqrt{a} x_1)\cos(\sqrt{b}x_2)$ which takes the same form (up to a constant factor) when operated on by $\left(\frac{\partial^2 }{\partial x_1^2}  + \frac{\partial^2 }{\partial x_2^2}\right)$.  In other words it is an eigenfunction.

Comment: @Grazel: The PDE is linear and your $f$ has no time dependence, so a particular solution in your case would be a sum of particular solutions $u_1 + u_2$ where $$ \frac{\partial^2 u_1}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2 u_1}{\partial y^2} = \exp \Big[-6\Big((x + \frac{1}{2})^2 + y^2\Big) \Big] $$ and $$ \frac{\partial^2 u_2}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2 u_2}{\partial y^2} = -\exp \Big[-6\Big((x - \frac{1}{2})^2 + y^2\Big) \Big] $$

Comment: @RRL Thank you so much.

Comment: @Grazel: In your case the particular solution takes the form of an exponential integral $Ei$